# How can I prevent the OnSuccess script from firing if a partial view that contains an error message was returned

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I have the following Ajax.BeginForm inside my asp.net MVC web application :-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddZone", "DataCenter", 


    new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
    UpdateTargetId = "zonetableBody",
    LoadingElementId = "progress3",
    OnSuccess = "createsuccess",
    OnFailure="createfail"
}))
{
```

This will call the following action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "Zone")]
        public ActionResult AddZone(DataCenterDetails z)
        {
```

I am performing a custom authorization action filter before executing the action methods, as follow:-

```
namespace TMS.Controllers
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]

    public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            int value = 0;
            Repository repository = new Repository();

            if (!repository.can(ADusername,Model,value))


                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {

                    var viewResult = new PartialViewResult();

                    viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml";
                    filterContext.Result = viewResult;
```

The problem I am facing is that if the user does not have the required permission to Edit , and he clicks on the ajax.beginform button he will receive the “/_Unauthorized.cshtml” view, but at the same time the Onsuccess script which display a message that the “Record was added successfully” will fire.

So my question is how I can prevent the Onsuccess script from being fired , in-case the `_Unauthorized.cshtml` is returned ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `filterContext.Response.StatusCode`. You can set it 500 or a code that does not mean OK;

Comment: but how i can pass this StatusCode , with the _Unauthorized.cshtml view ?

Comment: When you set the StatusCode the onsuccess will not be called. But you have the data (the html result of _unauthorized view) in client. you can get it by OnComplete method and update an html control using jquery.

Comment: Set the StatusCode in OnActionExecuting method.

Comment: so u mean i should set the statuscode to some number and at the same time ti retuen the -unauthorized view ?

Comment: Yes i do. you don't want the _Unauthorized view and onsuccess method at the same time. do you?

Comment: Response.StatusCode = 401; or
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;

Answer (score 1):

**I.** AjaxOptions have OnComplete property which occurs before a call to either OnSuccess or OnFailure. To cancel the page update, return false from the JavaScript function.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.oncomplete(v=vs.118).aspx

**II.** In case if you need global error handling for ajax request you should use `.ajaxError()`

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
    if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 400) {
        window.location == "/Error";           
    }
});
```

Hope this helps